# Axios take off the async

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

How can i make the same code without the async function?

```
async EnvioLogin() {
  const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  });
  localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
},
```

I tried:

```
EnvioLogin() {
  const response = axios.post("api/auth/login", {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  });
  localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
},
```

But im getting this error:

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined"

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's an asynchronous operation.

Comment: `axios.post(..etc...).then(response => localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);` - the localStorage.setItem is still executed asynchronously - so if you intent was to remove asynchrony, there is no way to do that

Comment: I didnt know  that. Im having trouble with async, cant make it work without errors. Thanks for the tip, i will look for solutions

Comment: You need the async to do that, or you will get errors all the time, if you need any help could you log the payload response. Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to not use async / await keywords, you can go with promises.

```
axios.post("api/auth/login", {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  }).then((response)=>{localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);})
```